# How to get the uuid of the mainboard with c

Tags: c, windows

I need a code snippet for reading the mainboard uuid in c (in Windows XP and Windows Vista if there is a difference, else just for Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072.aspx) shows how to use Windows Management Instrumentation APIs to read information about the local computer. It doesn't access the "UUID" (which I guess would be the motherboard's serial number) directly, but it should be possible to get there by modifying the example.

Also notice the [Win32_BaseBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072.aspx) WMI class, it has a `SerialNumber` member.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from WMI. Try this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558(VS.85).aspx) for WMI via c/c++

But I could only find this [example](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2664) in vb